# Separate program to install & configure console app?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, installation, settings

I have a simple console app that clients will install on their server which sends data to our API. They need to type in their username/password for our API and the program remembers this and uses it when the app is run using a daily scheduled task.

**How can I create a GUI to let the end user type in their username/password (for our API) which the console app can read?** Since the app needs installed (xcopy + set up of scheduled task), I presume I can do this in the same program?

Currently I'm using the Visual Studio Application Settings to store the username/password when they are passed as parameters to the app. When the app is run without parameters, it uses the stored data (which is encrypted with DPAPI).

Comment: you could start a WinForm when your console app is started with /setup as command argument...

Comment: @rene is the WinForm then a separate program? could you go into more detail? I'm not sure about how the console app and the WinForm app can both read the same encrypted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two option :

- Open a WinForm
- Ask the user name and password interactively directly in the console application

As suggested by rene you can use a switch on the command line of the same application, or you can create a separate application to do it, in the case of a separate application maybe the winForm solution would be the best choice.

Comment: What I'm wondering if its possible to use a Visual Studio Setup Project and spawn off a configuration program - a WinForm that asks for these details and saves them in a way which the console app can read it too. Could this work?

Comment: any idea how I can share encrypted passwords with both programs?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm, for some algorithm you can share private key for example ...

Comment: @IgorK It is possible to run a WinForm app from Visual Studio Setup Project, yet you better integrate these dialogs into your Setup Wizard. The latter is not supported in the Visual Studio setup. As another option, you can create a shortcut in Start menu which will allow users to change their settings.

Comment: @IgorK The disadvantage of creating a WinForm from a console application is that the console is created and you don't need it in this case. However, I think it is possible to disconnect from the console in configuration mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to create separate installer.
Just check in your console app if the settings contains standard password? If yes - prompt for a new one. It means you don't need to create separate interface for installer.

Comment: I have to have an installer of some sort anyway which should xcopy the app and it's dependencies plus set up the scheduled task.

There is around 4 or 5 fields I have to store from the user, I'd prefer not to have this in the console app from a usability point of view.

Comment: Some sort of installer - it's what sort?